# change src of img with js

Tags: javascript, html

Using following code the src of image changes only between "width-1.gif" and "width-2.gif". How to fix this code to give the src also value of "width-3.gif" and "width-4.gif" when window width has resized?

```js
var img = document.getElementById('img');

var changeSize = function () {
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 993) {
        img.setAttribute('src', 'images/width-1.gif')
    } else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 992 || document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 871) {
        img.setAttribute('src', 'images/width-2.gif')
    } else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 870 || document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 786) {
        img.setAttribute('src', 'images/width-3.gif')
    } else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 785) {
        img.setAttribute('src', 'images/width-4.gif')
    }
};

window.addEventListener("resize", changeSize);
```

Comment: your code is ok, I guess your window does not get the width to trigger your images 3 and 4

Comment: I think you are using || when you should be using && to make it fall in the range.

Answer (score 3):

Use **&&** instead of **||**

```
var changeSize = function () {
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 993) {
        img.setAttribute('src', 'images/width-1.gif')
    } else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 992 && document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 871) {
        img.setAttribute('src', 'images/width-2.gif')
    } else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 870 && document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 786) {
        img.setAttribute('src', 'images/width-3.gif')
    } else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 785) {
        img.setAttribute('src', 'images/width-4.gif')
    }
};
```

Comment: If my answer worked please approve it (check the tick sign on the left part of answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your ORs (||) to ANDs (&&).  In the example above, any value below 992 will be satisfied by the first condition `document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 992` and the expression will automatically return true.  Try the below instead:

```
var changeSize = function () {
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 993) {
    img.setAttribute('src', 'images/width-1.gif')
} else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 992 &&     document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 871) {
    img.setAttribute('src', 'images/width-2.gif')
} else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 870 && document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 786) {
    img.setAttribute('src', 'images/width-3.gif')
} else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 785) {
    img.setAttribute('src', 'images/width-4.gif')
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Your second if statement checks `if width<=922 OR width>=871` which is always true for any number. It can be easily fixed by using `&&`, or, you can just take advantage of nested for loops:

```
var changeSize = function () {
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 993) {
        img.setAttribute('src', 'images/width-1.gif')
    } else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 871) {
        img.setAttribute('src', 'images/width-2.gif')
    } else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 786) {
        img.setAttribute('src', 'images/width-3.gif')
    } else {
        img.setAttribute('src', 'images/width-4.gif')
    }
};
```